# Dynamic Cell Width In Compositional Layout

Tags: swift, uikit, collectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am looking to achieve the below illustration. Essentially it is a horizontal 'section' within a UICompositionalLayout where the cells size to the text.

[image: illustration of horizontal section]

The issue I am having is that if the cell doesn't fit onto the screen it will offset to the next screen page.

Here is my code:

```
fileprivate func createNavigationButtonSection(using section: HomeSection) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        let estimatedHeight: CGFloat = 40
        let estimatedWidth: CGFloat = 100
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(estimatedWidth),
                                              heightDimension: .estimated(estimatedHeight))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        item.edgeSpacing = NSCollectionLayoutEdgeSpacing(leading: nil,
                                                         top: nil,
                                                         trailing: .fixed(8),
                                                         bottom: nil)
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                                               heightDimension: .estimated(estimatedHeight))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize,
                                                       subitems: [item])
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
        return section
    }
```

This is the effect it is giving where it pushes the last cell

[image: gif illustration]

### UPDATE

```
fileprivate var navigationButtons: [NavigationButton] = [
        NavigationButton(image: UIImage(named: "heart"), title: "Saved", query: "item_saved"),
        NavigationButton(image: UIImage(named: "grid"), title: "Categories", query: "item_categories"),
        NavigationButton(image: UIImage(named: "deal"), title: "Deals", query: "item_deals"),
        NavigationButton(image: UIImage(named: "clock"), title: "Latest", query: "item_latest"),
    ]

fileprivate var sections = [HomeSection]()
```

In ViewDidLoad:

```
sections = [HomeSection(title: nil, subtitle: nil, section_type: "navigationButtons", item: navigationButtons)]
```

Comment: Can you show us where you update the data source? It looks like the last item might be in its own section.

Comment: @Owen26 I've updated in the question. I think it has something to do with the group width. If I change let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), to fractional width to (2) it spaces correctly, but the padding at the end of the group is off.

Comment: What happens when you use the following for the group declaration: `let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: itemSize, subitems: [item])`

Comment: @Owen26 This seems to be working it gives all the items together I just need to put spacing in between them. As they are all touching.

Comment: You can then use `group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(20)` for example to space the items in the group.

Comment: This doesn't affect the spacing for some reason?

Comment: My mistake, it's `section.interGroupSpacing = 20` you'll need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237708/discussion-between-owen26-and-david-lintin).

Comment: @DavidLintin, can you able to resolved this. I have facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work and provide the outcome you're after. We'll use the itemSize for the group size and to make sure the items are separated we'll add some `interGroupSpacing` to the section to spread the groups out.

```
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: itemSize, subitems: [item])
...
section.interGroupSpacing = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just add **interGroupSpacing** in section and Put Same **NSCollectionLayoutSize** to item and group

```
 fileprivate func createNavigationButtonSection(using section: HomeSection) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        let estimatedHeight: CGFloat = 40
        let estimatedWidth: CGFloat = 100
        let size = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(estimatedWidth),
                                              heightDimension: .estimated(estimatedHeight))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: size)
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: size,
                                                       subitems: [item])
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 8
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
        return section
    }
```